# MKMapview with google maps data

Tags: mkmapview

[This link states that mkmapview is based on apple maps data][1]

```
But Is that possible to make the MKMapview to use google maps data, am using xcode 6 and iOS 8

Please suggest,

Thanks in advance

  [1]:
```

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Maps_on_iOS_7_with_MapKit_and_the_MKMapView_Class

Comment: No, use the Google Maps for iOS SDK instead.

Comment: is that possible to use all the stuff of MKMapview similarly on google maps sdk,

Comment: I want to add custom maps with more static polygons so is that posible to use the kml files?